# How to output every possible field for a resource using --format=table in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

According to the documentation for the Cloud SDK - [gcloud topic formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats), it supplies an option `--format` that effectively controls the way your output looks.

I noticed, that when I use `--format=json` or `--format=yaml` with no additional arguments, `gcloud` produces an output that concludes every available field to be retrieved with this API, however, I was unable to figure out, how to reach the same kind of behavior with `--table` without the need of enumerating every single field of service.

Consider the following example:

```
gcloud app regions list --format=json --limit 1
```

```json
[
  {
    "flexible": true,
    "region": "asia-east1",
    "search_api": false,
    "standard": true
  }
]
```

It shows an exhaustive enumeration of available fields for AppEngine region resource, yet when I want to output pretty much the same information, especially where I don't know exactly the full scope of fields or the exact naming, I ought to enumerate each of them individually like as follows.

```bash
gcloud app regions list \
--format="table[box,all-box,title='AppEngine APAC regions'](region,standard,flexible,search_api)" \
--limit 9
```

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                               AppEngine APAC regions                               │
├──────────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬─────────────────────┤
│        REGION        │ SUPPORTS STANDARD │ SUPPORTS FLEXIBLE │ SUPPORTS GAE SEARCH │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-east1           │ YES               │ YES               │ NO                  │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-east2           │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-northeast1      │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-northeast2      │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-northeast3      │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-south1          │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-southeast1      │ YES               │ YES               │ NO                  │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ asia-southeast2      │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ australia-southeast1 │ YES               │ YES               │ YES                 │
```

In summary, is there a simpler way to achieve mentioned behaviour with `--table` format something like this

```bash
gcloud app regions list --format="table" --limit 9 # Won't work
```

For a reference, here is an example using tabular view representation according to [AWS table output format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html#table-output) with no additional parameters being supplied

```bash
aws iam list-users --output table
```

Produces the following output

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                 ListUsers                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
||                                                                                  Users                                                                      ||
|+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+|
||                         Arn                        |       CreateDate          |    PasswordLastUsed       |   Path   |        UserId         |   UserName  ||
|+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+|
||  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Admin              | 2014-10-16T16:03:09+00:00 | 2016-06-03T18:37:29+00:00 | /        | AIDA1111111111EXAMPLE | Admin       ||
||  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/backup/backup-user | 2019-09-17T19:30:40+00:00 |                           | /backup/ | AIDA2222222222EXAMPLE | backup-user ||
||  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/cli-user           | 2019-09-17T19:11:39+00:00 |                           | /        | AIDA3333333333EXAMPLE | cli-user    ||
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The [documentation for `--table`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats#table) explains "This format requires a projection to define the table columns".

It's not an unreasonable request but I suspect the reason is that tables are better|best-suited to flat|non-hierarchical data. It's possible that nested types could be output as nested tables but this could become messy.

What are you trying to achieve that you're unable to do as-is?

You can determine the API calls that underlie any `gcloud` command by appending the flag `--log-http`.

Then, using [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), you can locate these methods e.g. [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/), here's [`apps.locations.list`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.locations/list) and ... finally... the response type. In this case [`ListLocationsResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ListLocationsResponse).

And, this type corresponds to the output of e.g. `gcloud app regions list`.

Comment: Great point you made on tabular representation of hierarchical data , since it is indeed may come up as quite non-trivial task. To me, personally, I found table output format as more human-readable compared to others, but again, I'm talking about a use case of quickly browsing and picking the most important stuff - like healthcheck statuses, status of the latest CloudBuild job, etc, rather than rigorously exploring APIs.

Comment: Understood. The default format is also generally a good synopsis of the output.